# Why the stream doesn't work in parallel mode?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a code :

```
rows = types.stream().parallel().map(s -> {
    switch (s){
        case NDBaseDocumentModel.DOC_TYPE_NSS:
            return getDocsOfSpecificTypeAndCountItsDupes(NDGostStandardsModel.TYPE_ND_GOST_STANDARDS, null,systemMessages.getString("form20.nss.name")).values();
        case NDBaseDocumentModel.DOC_INT_REG_STANDARDS:
            return getDocsOfSpecificTypeAndCountItsDupes(NDIntRegStandardsModel.TYPE_ND_INT_REG_STANDARDS, null,systemMessages.getString("form20.int_reg")).values();
    }
    return new HashSet<Form20Row>();
}).flatMap(o -> {
    return o.stream();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And it doesn't work (return zero rows), but work fine when I remove "parallel()" call (14 rows on same data). Could somebody tell me why, please??
Please?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with something simplified like `Stream.of("a", "b", "c").parallel() .map(s -> List.of(s.toUpperCase())).flatMap(o -> o.stream()) .collect(Collectors.toList());` which may suggest that problem is in parts not included in the question.

Comment: Same here. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to use `map(…).flatMap(o -> o.stream())`. You can use a single `flatMap(…)` step, letting the alternatives return a `Stream` in the first place. Then, you don’t need to create a new `HashSet` in the fallback, as you could just return `Stream.empty()` or even `null`. The duplication of two `stream()` in the two cases would be acceptable here (compared to having to chain another stream operation).

Comment: What do you mean "use a single flatMap(…)"? I have a stream of the streams, how to concatenate them?

Answer (score 1):

Parallel streams are processed using a thread pool, and as such your method `getDocsOfSpecificTypeAndCountItsDupes` needs to be thread-safe.

As removing the `parallel()` and processing it on the same thread fixes your issue, it seems likely that there's something in the method that isn't thread-safe, which will be your problem.

Comment: it's looks like true